# Determine if a GPS location is within a gpx track segment

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, gps, gpx

I have this .gpx file that is formatted as follows:

```
<trk>
<name>Area1</name>
<extensions>
<gpxx:TrackExtension>
<gpxx:DisplayColor>Magenta</gpxx:DisplayColor>
</gpxx:TrackExtension>
</extensions>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="52.806521779700120" lon="5.795177063346190"/>
...
<trkpt lat="52.806521779700120" lon="5.795177063346190"/>
</trkseg>
</trk>
<trk>
<name>Area2</name>
<extensions>
<gpxx:TrackExtension>
<gpxx:DisplayColor>Magenta</gpxx:DisplayColor>
</gpxx:TrackExtension>
</extensions>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="52.764805147811629" lon="5.377259838276261"/>
...
```

This file that contains well over 18.000 coordinates, describes several (adjacent) areas.

My ultimate goal is to see, if a given GPS coordinate is within the borders of any of these areas. What would be the best approach for that?

Related, intermediate question:
Will any method be reasonable fast to run through all these coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution to check if a point is inside an polygonal area without holes**

Just use a point-In-polygon function. And use x for longitude and y for latitude. You can directly pass in the long, lat cordinates.
Such a function is easily found here or via google.
E.g here, 7 lines of code: https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html

The only possibility that this function fail, is when the region overlaps the datum limit (meridian at longitude -180, 180).
However since there is mostly water, it is unlikely that the region will overlap that line.
18.000 points is no problem for this task, there is no need for advanced algorithms.

Comment: Dear Alex, I do appreciate your answer. In the mean time, I found a web service, that does most of the trick for me. Since I don't even know what a cartesian space is , I'm afraid I'm not entitled to classify your answer as correct. Hopefully, a future visitor is.

Comment: ok, i thought you need to write a program for that, If you just need it for a one time shot, or a demo system, a web service will work. A cartesian space is an x,y coordinate system, as you used in school. GPS coordinates are located on  a sphere, so it is not an cartesian space. To make school mathematics work, you need to transform from spherical coordinates  to flat cartesian.

Comment: I see. Much appreciated.

Comment: It seems I have not well read your question, I have updated, since the task is much easier.

Comment: Wow, seven lines. While I have already solved my particular situation, i will study this.